# Is there a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients such that $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=3$, $f(4)=4$, and $f(5)=17$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was wondering if there exists a **polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients** that satisfies $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=3$, $f(4)=4$, and $f(5)=17$.

I thought there such polynomial would exist because $m-n$ divides $f(m)-f(n)$ for every pair of integers $m$ and $n$. However, I failed to find real evidence that such polynomial exists.

(By the way, if we are finding **polynomial with rational number coefficients** , there is an answer. See [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial))

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: If such polynomial with integer coefficients exists then Lagrange interpolation polynomial has integer coefficients. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169083/lagrange-interpolation-and-integer-polynomials

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ satisfying $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=3$, $f(4)=4$, and $f(5)=17$ is of the form $$\begin{align}f(x)&=x+\frac12\,(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\\
&\phantom{aaaaa}+(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)\,P(x)\end{align}$$
for some $P(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$.  Thus, $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ if and only if
$$Q(x):=(x-5)\,P(x)+\frac12\in\mathbb{Z}[x]\,.$$
However, if $Q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, then $Q(5)\in\mathbb{Z}$, but 
$$Q(5)=\frac12\notin\mathbb{Z}\,,$$
which is a contradiciton.  Therefore, $f(x)$ cannot have integral coefficients.

The condition that $m-n$ must divide $f(m)-f(n)$ for all $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a necessary condition for $f(x)$ to have integral coefficients.  However, as the paragraph above illustrates, this is not a sufficient condition.  From the [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/169083/lagrange-interpolation-and-integer-polynomials), given by Robert Z, we have the following result.

> **Proposition.**  Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{Z}$ be such that $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ are pairwise distinct.  For $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n\in\mathbb{Z}$, there exists a polynomial $f(t)\in\mathbb{Z}[t]$ for which $f\left(x_i\right)=y_i$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ if and only if the Lagrange interpolation polynomial $L(t)$ of the points $\left(x_1,y_1\right)$, $\left(x_2,y_2\right)$, $\ldots$, $\left(x_n,y_n\right)$ has integral coefficients.